# How to go back from the native notebook experience in vscode Jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

So today my ipynb files were now opening in the native notebook experience and I want to revert back to as it was before. I tried installing previous versions of the jupyter extension but it's still opening my ipynb files in the native experience only. Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

open your settings JSON (press F1 or Windows: Ctrl + Shift + P, Mac: Command + Shift + P)

add the following to your JSON settings:

```
"jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"],
```

restart vscode and check if you have the old version back.

Comment: Thanks I just installed a previous version of VSCode